# ActiveModel Serializer not working for function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, active-model-serializers

I am using [ActiveModelSerialziers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) in my Rails API and it works like a charm but 1 of my functions seems to override it, and only returns my model (without any of the associations).  The same model returns properly if a different function is called.

```
  def getClient
    type = params[:type]

    if type == 'user'
      @client = Client.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
    else
      @client = Client.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end


    render json: { success: true, response: @client }
  end
```

only returns the `client` without the associations and the serializer is:

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

    attributes :name, :age, :address

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :check_ins
    has_many :client_docs
    has_many :payments
end
```

While the same model (`Client`) returns properly (with associations) when the following function is called:

```
  def show
    model_name = params[:model].classify
    item = model_name.constantize.find_by(id: params[:id])

    render json: item, status: :ok
  end
```

Why might this happen?

Comment: try this `render json: { success: true, response:  ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@client, serializer: ClientSerializer }`

Comment: That works!  But why do I need to specify

Comment: are you finding by ` Client.find_by(user_id: params[:id])` ?

Comment: In this case, yes.  Would that cause it?

Comment: yes. does my code resolve your issue ?

Comment: it does resolve the issue though I feel I should be able to use the serializer without specifying

Answer (score 0):

You are missing adapter: :json from the rander statement:

```
render json: item, adapter: :json, status: :ok
```